# changing a button's text from another method when the buttons are in a subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, class, text

How do you access a button that's in a subview of a view?

I have a viewController 'GamePlay', which has a scrollview in it called 'gameScroll'. **Within this scrollview** I have about 100 buttons, each with a tag, and I want to be able to change the text of the button **from another method.**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  //Created buttons in a for-loop, assigning each a tag
    //numOfButtons is total number of buttons created
}
```

I imagine it would be something like this? but I cant seem to find an answer on exactly how i do it when the button is in a subview

```
- (void) otherMethod {

  for (int i=0; i<numOfButtons; i++) {
    // tagsForAction = get list of buttons that need to be changed from another array

    for (j=0; j<tagsForAction.length; j++) {
      intTagForAction = [tagsForAction objectAtIndex:j];

      if (i = tagForAction) {
        UIButton* button = [Gameplay.gameScroll.view viewWithTag:tagForAction];
        button.title = @"A";
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

I know this code isnt totally right. Im just giving you an idea of the process. I can do everything except this part in the if statement:

```
UIButton* button = [Gameplay.gameScroll.view viewWithTag:tagForAction];
button.title = @"A";
```

**so how do I change the text of these buttons?**

Comment: Without getting too involved in your code I believe your error is here `if (i = tagForAction)` instead of `if (i == tagForAction)` ??

Comment: So accessing .title of the button in question in your posted code does not work? How about [myButton setTitle: ...]? Or as a final test, rather than re-create the button, can you access it directly (assuming all properties are set and synthesized - unless your views are stricly programmatic and not subclasses?) eg, myView.someSubView.myButton.title = @"blah"; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *subViewList = [gameScroll subviews];
for (id button in subViewList)
{
    if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
                [button setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
    }
```

**Try this code**

Comment: this worked great thanks! I ended up nesting it inside of my own for loops and if statements though because it seemed to change all of the subviews. not too hard so this was a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the `for` loop like that, you can get an array of subviews from any view by doing something like `[someView subviews]`. So, inside of your `otherMethod` function you can do something like:

```
for (UIView *v in [gameScroll subviews]) {
    if (v.tag == <some_int_here>) {
        [v setTitle:@"Some other title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what your criteria is for determining which buttons inside the `gameScroll` view have to get updated, but you can work from here.

Comment: hey thanks i think this is pretty similar to what i did. I couldnt use this one though because i wasnt able to call properties like title on the view. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. If you wanna use a loop like this in the future, you can do something like this to access specific properties of the object: `UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)v`. Then you can get things like `btn.titleLabel`. (Just don't forget to do a check on the view first to make sure it is of the type you're expecting by using `isKindOfClass`.)